# Trouble with nn.embedding in pytorch, expected scalar type Long, but got torch.cuda.FloatTensor (how to fix)?

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

so I have an RNN encoder that is part of a larger language model, where the process is encode -> rnn -> decode.

As part of my `__init__` for my rnn class I have the following:

```py
self.encode_this = nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.embedded_vocab_dim)
```

now I am trying to implement a forward class, which takes in batches and performs encoding then decoding,

```py
def f_calc(self, batch):
    #Here, batch.shape[0] is the size of batch while batch.shape[1] is the sequence length

    hidden_states = (torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch.shape[0], self.hidden_vocab_dim).to(device))
    embedded_states = (torch.zeros(batch.shape[0],batch.shape[1], self.embedded_vocab_dim).to(device))

    o1, h = self.encode_this(embedded_states)
```

however, my problem is always with the encoder which gives me the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1465         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   1466         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 1467     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1468 
   1469 

RuntimeError: Expected tensor for argument #1 'indices' to have scalar type Long; but got torch.cuda.FloatTensor instead (while checking arguments for embedding)
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix? I am completely new to pytorch so please excuse me if this is a stupid question. I know there is some form of type casting involved but I am not sure how to go about doing it...

much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Embedding layer expects integers at the input.

```
import torch as t

emb = t.nn.Embedding(embedding_dim=3, num_embeddings=26)

emb(t.LongTensor([0,1,2]))
```

[image]

Add `long()` in your code:

```
embedded_states = (torch.zeros(batch.shape[0],batch.shape[1], self.embedded_vocab_dim).to(device)).long()
```

Comment: When I do this and pass it through my rnn, self.rnn(embedded_states) a whole new dimension is added... so the tensor becomes 4d instead of 3d, do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Because you do embedding: you replace integers in the last dimension with their embeddings! In other words, you replace the number (scalar) with a vector and add an extra dimension.

Comment: Hmm, do you have any idea how to keep it 3D ? I’ve been trying the squeeze method but it doesn’t seem to work. The input to my RNN is 3D and not 4D... and I’m supposedly passing in 3D embeddings and hidden states right? Or am I doing this wrong completely?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing your idea. You can see my code [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/27837). I am doing character embedding. At the input I have [sentences, words, characters]. I represent each character with it's embedding (now I have [sentences, words, characters, embeddings] and use LSTM to get the embedding of words. And then apply LSTM to the words to solve the classification problem.

Comment: Well my input is of the form N*L where N is batch size and L is sequence length, my output is to be an N * L * V where V is the vocab size (an embedding for each word)... now my initialization of embedded states is that 3d vector of zeroes (batch size, sequence length, dim of embedding) but now when I run nn.embedding I'm getting a whole extra dimension

Comment: `embedded_states = (torch.zeros(batch.shape[0],batch.shape[1]).to(device)).long()`

Comment: Thanks for this!  I got that far with my endeavor, and all the outputs and inputs are fine. Yet my perplexity and loss function seem to yield super high results which is unfavorable, need to find something else...